# multiprocessing: pool: wait for all results, but process individual results immediately

Tags: python

I have a list of tasks I would like to distribute to workers in a pool. I would like to achieve two things:

1. Whenever a worker is finished, process the result immediately
2. Have a simple way to wait for all workers to finish.

Using fapply_async, I can easily achieve the first goal. Whenever a worker has finished, the callback gets invoked. However, to achieve the second goal, the only solution I could come up with basically just polls the AsyncResults until they are all ready().

Using map_async, I can easily achieve the second goal. However, the callback gets invoked only once, when all workers have finished. I believe I understand the reason for this (the order of the results is relevant).

Is there some solution I'm missing that would achieve both goal 1 and 2?

Here's my test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import multiprocessing
import time
import random

def worker(src):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    # src is apply_async or map_async
    return (src, random.randint(1, 100))

def map_async_example():
    tasks = ['map_async'] * 20
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        r = pool.map_async(worker, tasks, callback=print)
        r.wait()

def fapply_async_example():
    tasks = [('fapply_async',)] * 20
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        ars = []
        for t in tasks:
            ar = pool.apply_async(worker, t, callback=print)
            ars.append(ar)
        # Wait for all AsyncResults to become ready()
        while len(ars) > 0:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            # Keep only the not-ready results
            ars = [ar for ar in ars if not ar.ready()]

def main():
    # One list of 20 results
    print('===============')
    print('Using map_async')
    print('===============')
    map_async_example()

    # 20 results
    print('==================')
    print('Using fapply_async')
    print('==================')
    fapply_async_example()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just do your processing and then [`join()`](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html#waiting-for-processes) them all at the end?

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thanks! I misinterpreted the effect of the necessary prior call to close(), so I didn't try that.